# Java CUBA Platform filter how use?

Tags: java, filter, cuba

The problem is that the cube filter uses loadContext . But I redefine the method responsible for loading data and do not use loadcontext, but form a response for the front in the program. How do I apply a filter?

```
    @Install(to = "workProcessesDl", target = Target.DATA_LOADER)
    private List<ContractHistoryWorkProcess> workProcessesDlLoadDelegate(LoadContext<ContractHistoryWorkProcess> loadContext) {

        return getEditedEntity().getCustomers().stream().flatMap(c -> c.getFacilities().stream()).flatMap(
                f -> f.getWorkProcesses().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

I want to apply a filter to the collection that I'm forming, which is set by the user. But the problem is that the filters work with the database, and my collection is formed programmatically, without queries to the database.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?  If you are, please put the exact wording of the error message in your post.

Comment: There is no mistake. It's just that I want to apply a filter to the collection that I'm forming, which is set by the user. But the problem is that the filters work with the database, and my collection is formed programmatically, without queries to the database

Comment: Won't Java Streams work for any collection in Java?  Pretty sure you don't need a database connection to make them work.

Comment: I want to change this filter to my collection https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-latest/gui_Filter.html